# Better pane navigation in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I'm currently in a tmux window (v1.9a) with six panes, arranged in 2 columns and 3 rows. I built this window with % (5x), then M-5 for the arrangement. q shows the following numbering:

`0 | 1
2 | 3
4 | 5`

The setup works well for the most part, but when switching panes with the arrow keys, tmux seems to group the rows and remember the last pane.

Example: I'm in pane 3, I press C-b, Up, Left, to get to Pane 0. Now I press C-b, Down, to get to Pane 2, but it brings me to 3, since that's the last pane I was in on that row.

Is there some "absolute down" mapping I could create? Or a "remember pane" setting I could disable?

Comment: Interestingly I can't reproduce this for the layout created with `prefix + M-5`. I do experience the behavior sometimes with different pane arrangements.